# sails lift - failed - how lift the app?

Tags: sails.js

Hello i have a tried to lift my sails app.. but now i get this back 
This is the source of the terminal. on my mac !

```
Space-Od-Mac-Pro:git1 cyberspace$ sails lift
-bash: /usr/local/bin/sails: No such file or directory
Space-Od-Mac-Pro:gitt1 cyberspace$
```

how fix that? i tried to many things install node etc.. but how can i do that? 
i have tried to install noce.js and npm right? but isnt work i get this path back 
how change this that i can sails lift my app.?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to install sails globally to be able to run `sails`. `npm install -g sails` would install it globally but you may need to run it as sudo.